# MultiMarkDown and biblatex citations

Tags: biblatex, natbib

I'm using Scrivener to produce LaTeX output with MultiMarkDown. MultiMarkDown uses `natbib` by default, so footnotes look like this code snips:

```
\footnote{~\citep[<prenote>]{<key>}}
```

The issue is that I need to use biblatex. I can get the footnotes and citations to parse by doing two things: (1) specifying the `natbib` option in the `\usepackage{biblatex-chicago}` command and (2) using `\renewcommand{\citep}{\Cite}`

The problem is that `\footenote{\cite{}}` doesn't work the same in biblatex as `\footcite` or `\autocite`. The first variant doesn't automatically produce proper punctuation after the citation, whereas the latter two variants do.

What I'm trying to figure out is how to replace the two nested commands

```
\footnote{~\citep[<prenote>]{<key>}}
```

into a single `\autocite` command that takes prenote and key as its arguments. Notice that MMD automatically inserts a `~` before the `\citep` command -- I imagine I'd have to remove that, as well, for this to work properly. The full `.tex` file:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[left=1in, right=1in, bottom=1in, top=1in]{geometry}
\geometry{letterpaper}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{keyval}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[notes,natbib,footmarkoff]{biblatex-chicago} 

% Euro-Symbol
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{appendix}

\usepackage{hyperref}

% Use utf-8 encoding for foreign characters
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% This is now the recommended way for checking for PDFLaTeX:
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\usepackage{times}

\renewcommand{\citep}{\Cite}

\ifpdf
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\else
\usepackage{graphicx}
\fi

\addbibresource{Dissertation.bib}
\bibliocommand

\begin{document}

% TOC
\pagenumbering{roman}
\tableofcontents
\pagebreak

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\doublespacing

Trying to get this footnote to look normal.\footnote{~\citep[22]{Schelling:08}}

\pagebreak
\singlespacing
\printbibliography
\appendix
\end{document}
```

Please forgive me if this is an obvious question--I'm new to LaTeX, so any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Comment: @Guido - thanks! I'll keep that in mind for future posts.

Comment: I haven't used `MultiMarkDown` but have for a month been using `pandoc`. I haven't tested it in documents with bibliography citations but if you are interested, you can see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14288699/pandoc-not-converting-latex-style-citations-correctly and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3594311/what-is-the-most-mature-and-maintained-markdown-processor/7181696#7181696. Thanks for mentioning MultiMarkDown anyway. Might be worth to look at.

Comment: @GeneG. [Looks like](http://fletcherpenney.net/2011/03/multimarkdown_3.0b11_released) MMD uses `[#citekey;]` (note the semi-colon) for inline citations avoiding the `~`. MMD only supports a few citation commands from natbib and biblatex offers a whole lot more on top of its natbib-compatible commands. Your issue might be better addressed with a [feature request](https://github.com/fletcher/peg-multimarkdown/issues) to the MMD authors.

Comment: @Audrey I've actually converted to using that inline citation syntax from MMD. The LaTeX output is `\citet{}`, so I use `\renewcommand{\citet}{\Autocite}` in my preamble. It doesn't have the advantage of auto-punctuation that an in-line `\autocite` command has, but like you said, MMD unfortunately doesn't support the more advanced features of `biblatex` at the moment. Incidentally, is there a way to automatically check for whitespace after the superscript in a footnote and insert it if it is not present?

Comment: @GeneG. Extending your `\citep` redefinition idea, you could try `\pretocmd{\@footnotetext}{\begingroup\renewrobustcmd{\citep}{\unspace\Cite}}{}{}` and `\apptocmd{\@footnotetext}{\endgroup}{}{}`. Wrap those in `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` in your preamble. This allows you to use the usual `\citep` in the document body. Is this what you're after, though? I'm not sure. A solution incorporating some changes to your MMD syntax would likely be better.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use [`pandoc`](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) instead of MultiMarkDown. I have used biblatex with it and it works wonderfully with footnote style citations as you apparently use them.